# Storing Json response in a cookie /session using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, session, cookies

Once I login, I have customer_id in  success response . I need to store this customer_id somewhere in cookie or session and then need to pass it in next request of updating user profile. 
Please do assist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies).

Following snipet is just for code sample. (Cookies doesn't work in snippets, because of security policy).

Here is working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cq1EzG?p=preview

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('appController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    
    var vm = this;
    
    // Retrieving a cookie
    vm.favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('var');
    
    // Setting a cookie
    if (!vm.favoriteCookie)
    {
      $cookies.put('var', 'value');
      vm.message = 'Cookies var set to "value"';
    }
    else
    {
      vm.message = 'Your cookies var: ' + vm.favoriteCookie;
    }
    
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```